# ¿Cómo creo un trigger en phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, trigger

llevo días intentando ejecutar estos dos triggers en Phpmyadmin y obtengo error de sintaxis, no estoy seguro de donde puede estar el fallo, cualquier ayuda me vendría genial. Gracias

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_referencia_producto
AFTER INSERT ON prstshp_product
BEGIN
update prstshp_product set reference = (SELECT concat('R-', SUBSTRING(conv(UUID(),20,10), 4))) where reference is NULL or reference ='';
END;//


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_referencia_atributo
AFTER INSERT ON prstshp_product_attribute
BEGIN
update prstshp_product_attribute set reference = (SELECT concat('R-', SUBSTRING(conv(UUID(),20,10), 4))) where reference is NULL or reference ='';
END;//
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho qué agregues el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: Por supuesto, no me acordé, te dejo el enlace aquí del error:
https://subefotos.com/ver/?59bcd3a7a356b414923f4dc16c08cd39o.png